# GNOME 3 shows a striped striped bar on top of the screen

Tags: 11.04, graphics, gnome

I recently installed the gnome-shell for natty,

I am getting a couple of strange graphical issues.

1) whenever I press the *super key*, or try to show the bottom menu I get a strange flickering, the whole screen gets munched up while it animates to show/hide.

2) The top bar has an awful effect: It has rainbow coloured stripes.
[image]

3) Some of the tooltips and dropdowns (not all of them, and its not application specific) are horribly skewed, They will have a massive angle on the text and the extreme right of the tooltip is cut off and appears on the extreme left of the tooltip.

How can I fix these?

If it helps I have a dell inspiron 1545.

Comment: I had the same problem, but installing the proper gfx card drivers fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, Got it working.

I was using the propriety driver for my graphics card.

After disabling it gnome3 is working perfectly ;D

Comment: I didn't notice the posted date....

Comment: how did you remove the propriety driver?

Comment: using the additional drivers dialog

Answer (score 0):

It is known that gnome 3 does not work well with unity.
The libs for unity are not compatible with gnome 3 and the shell and vica versa.
If you must try it out here are the live cd's though only for suse or fedora
http://gnome3.org/tryit.html