# Gnome 3 panel distorted graphics

Tags: gnome

I recently installed gnome 3 on ubuntu natty. Its working fine, except that the background on the panel is distored. What could be the problem?

[image: distored graphics in panel]

Thanks

Comment: if you installed from the ppa, then it's really outdated, if you compile it yourself you're definetly missing something.

Comment: installed from ppa, and I'm constantly upgrading the packages.. unless you mean the builds in the ppa are outdated?

Comment: yep the builds in the ppa are experimental and outdated, most people recommends to compile gnome 3 yourself to get the most out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *uninstall* gnome-accessibility-themes, and *install* gnome-themes-standard. 
That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.

The high level answer is: it's your graphics driver.

If you have installed a proprietary driver uninstall it, if not, check to see if there is one for your computer.

[For my laptop (dell inspiron 1545) I had to remove the driver.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37257/gnome-3-shows-a-striped-striped-bar-on-top-of-the-screen)

Comment: will try this...